# iOS - will my app work on iOS 7.0?

Tags: ios, ios7, deployment-target

I am new to iOS development, and my Xcode deployment target is configured to version 7.1. How can I know if it'll work for version 7.0?

Comment: Why don't you try changing the deployment target to 7.0 and find out? If you don't have the 7.0 SDK go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads and download it.

Comment: search for the changes made from ios 7.0 to ios 7.1 and if you are not using things that are added in 7.1 it will work. Here is the api changelog: https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/releasenotes/General/iOS71APIDiffs/index.html

Comment: First step would be to do just as @F1ank3r says and test your app in the 7.0 Simulator. Ideally you would need to test on a real device running iOS 7.0, but that can be hard to get your hands on (iOS devices can't be easily downgraded).

Comment: change the deployment target from iOS7.1 to iOS7.0 and test you app on an device with iOS7.0 – you will see immediately whether it works and how it works.

Comment: Silly question but well answered @F1ank3r.Exact answer is that if your deployment target is set to 7.1 then it won't run on versions lesser than 7.1

Answer (score 6):

As per Apple Guidelines, The deployment target setting specifies the lowest operating system version that your app will run on. So if you build any app with deployment target of 7.1, then you will not be able to support anything below that version.

Refer [Apple guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) for more details.